# Clear / Empty all contents of tbody element?

Tags: dart

How do I do this in dart?

After grabbing a tbody element, I would like to do call empty() on it, but that does not seem to exist:

```
var el = query('#search_results_tbody');
el.empty();
```

I tried this, but it is acting weird, I dont even understand what the result is!

```
el.nodes.forEach((c) {c.remove();});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the fastest and easiest way to do this at the moment is simply set the contents to empty:

```
var el = query('#search_results_tbody');
el.innerHtml = '';
```

`innerHtml` is pretty optimized these days on the browser, it should be quick.

Alternatively, you could also do this:

```
el.children.clear();
```

Where `children` is a `List<Element>` with a `clear()` method to clear the list.